# Improving HTML markup

Tags: html

I was given a test and the guy just said:

> Improve the html

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

All I can think of is to use the HTML5 `<header>`, `<section>` and `<footer>` tags, but I got no response and no feedback regarding how he would like it to be *improved*.

Beyond the tags is there anything else that could be done to *improve* the HTML?

Comment: Possibly change header main and footer to id, and indent/make spacings correct. Not much to improve, maybe he means to add content and CSS. You should ask him more of what he actually means...

Comment: Also, possible he wanted nesting. Who know with such a stupid vague question. Best to ask for clarification.

Comment: @GaryHayes Yeh, all he kept saying is improve it...

Comment: @TheGenieOfTruth yeah. I did but his response was improve it. I think this was a question to see how I react to certain moronic situations lol... Thanks for the feedback all!

Comment: What is "improved" for one application may be made worse for another. So really, it was probably more of a test of your personality rather than your coding ability... are you the type of person who asks questions, or are you the type of person who just plugs away at the problem for hours on end, costing him money, because you're too prideful to ask?

Comment: That makes sense. If you design a full fledged website, he may be impressed, or he might think you want to waste his time and money. You should ask questions about what "improve" entails.

Comment: If I repeatedly asked him what he meant, and all he could say was, "make it better", I would just leave, but not before telling him why. "If this is what it's like working with you in a production environment, I feel it would be a waste of time trying to ask you what you want to accomplish, and therefore a waste of time working with you."

Comment: Yeah haha, this is literally the most pathetic test to gauge a developers ability on. If people are employed from this, then they are likely employing half-wits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is probably supposed to be using the new HTML5 tags:

```
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

...but it depends on [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic).

Answer (score 0):

With **HTML4**, developers used their own id/class names to style elements: header, top, bottom, footer, menu, navigation, main, container, content, article, sidebar, topnav, etc.

This made it impossible for search engines to identify the correct web page content.

With the new **HTML5** elements `<header> <footer> <nav> <section> <article>`, this will become easier.

Answer (score -1):

You can't really "improve" this, but you can style it better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <!-- 
  Link styles and such, possibly JavaScript and CSS files
  -->
  <script src = "main.js"></script>
  <link href = "stylesheet.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <title>Untitled</title>
 </head>

 <body>

    <div class="header">

    </div>

    <div class="main">

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

    </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

This makes the HTML more valid and complete, and ready for development. Also, it lets you visualize every element. I can't think of anything else to improve it, unless your interviewer means to add styles to design a full website.

Comment: I have never seen anyone, ever put a space either side of `=` in this context, each to their own though, also see other answers before you say it can't be improved :P

Comment: @Zanderwar I think the phrase _“You can't really ‘improve’ this”_ in this answer means that there’s no _definitive_ way of doing it, rather than none at all.

Comment: There is a definitive way of doing it: convert it from HTML4 to HTML5 thus providing search engines greater mobility in discovering the primary content of each page. All this poster has done is taken the original code and wrapped it in a `body` tag. Bravo.